# How to extract the hour of this kind of timestamp?

Tags: r, get, hour

This is how my timestamp looks like

```
date1 = timestamp[1]

date1
[1] 07.01.2016 11:52:35
3455 Levels: 01.02.2016 00:11:52 01.02.2016 00:23:35 01.000:30:21    31.01.2016 23:16:18
```

When I try to extract the hour, I get an invalid 'trim' argument. Thank you !

```
 format(date1, "%I")

 Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  :
```

invalid 'trim' argument

How can I extract single components like the hour from this timestamp.

Comment: See the linked answer. And for more on formats see `?strptime`. There is an extensive list in the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R:

```
format(strptime(x,format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'), "%H")
[1] "11"
```

**data**

```
x <- as.factor("07.01.2016 11:52:35")
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @PierreLafortune :-)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to parse the time

```
d = strptime(date1,format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Then use lubridate to extract parts like hour etc.

```
library(lubridate)
hour(d)
minute(d)
```